# Node.js inside a loop in a callback function return statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

So my problem is that i delcared 2 variabled outside a loop and i got inside the loop a callback function what should return with an increase statement based if its errored or worked but like in this example if i return with that statement it only go through to the loop but dont change the variables outside how would i get this work?

code Example here:

```
    let Correct = 0;
    let Errors = 0;
    let someArray;
    for(let index = 0; index < someArray.length; index++) {
        const Input = someArray[index]
        functionWithAnCallback(Input, (err, output) => {
            if(err) return Errors++;
            //do stuff here that is not important
            return Correct++;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Why are you returning `Error` and `Correct`? It could be that is making the problem.

Comment: `return`ing from asynchronous callbacks is pointless. And the variables *do* get changed by the callback, they just won't have been changed by the end of the loop.

Comment: My answer before this was closed: https://pastebin.com/uPw3Vm8F